# max value of a tensor in graph mode tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I have this `tf` code in graph mode (it has a training function wrapped by `@tf.function`) where I need to get the max value of a tensor `x` with type

`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> Tensor("x_3:0", shape=(100,), dtype=int64)`.

Then I need to use the max value of `x` as one of the arguments in the `shape` argument of `tf.reshape()`. If I print the output of `tf.reduce_max(x)` I get `Tensor("Max:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)`, which is an invalid argument for `tf.reshape()`. I have tried `tf.reduce_max(x).numpy()` and it throws the error message `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

So how do I get the max value of a tensor in graph mode in `tf 2.6.0`?

**UPDATE** This is my code with the necessary details (I hope) to see what is going on:

MyModel.py

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, ...,hidden_size,name='model',**kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        x1, input, target, length, y = inputs
        batch_size = input.shape[0]
        print('check point 2', length, tf.reduce_max(length))
        padded_outputs = tf.reshape(tf.boolean_mask(outputs_dec,mask), shape=(batch_size,tf.reduce_max(length),self.hidden_size))
        print('check point 3',padded_outputs.shape)

    @tf.function
    def train(self, inputs, optimizer):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            costs = self.call(inputs)
        gradients = tape.gradient(self.loss, self.params)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.params))
```

train_mymodel.py

```
tr_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x1_tr,                                             
                                              x2.input, 
                                              x2.target, 
                                              x2.length,
                                              y_tr))\                           
                                             .batch(args.batch_size)
while int(checkpoint.step) < args.epochs:
            for i, (x1_batch, input_batch, target_batch, length_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(tr_data):
                print('check point 1', length_batch)
                costs, obj_fn = mymodel.train((x1_batch, input_batch, target_batch, length_batch, y_batch),optimizer)
```

```
check point 1 tf.Tensor([300 300 ... 300 300], shape=(100,),type=int64)
check point 2 Tensor("x_3:0", shape=(100,), dtype=int64) Tensor("Max_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)
check point 3 (100, None, 500)
```

The shape of padded_outputs should be `(100, 300, 500)`.

**UPDATE2** The error happens when the graph is traced. If I hard code `shape=(batch_size,300,self.hidden_size)` and use `tf.print(batch_size,tf.reduce_max(length),self.hidden_size)` then the code runs without error messages and the output of `tf.print()` is `(100,300,500)`. Is it any way to avoid such behavior?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: well it crashes latter on because it is expecting that the shape of padded_outputs is (100, 300, 500) and not (100, None, 500). The tf.reduce_max() should return 300 and not None.

Comment: Yes, please add the error message to your question.

Comment: At that point there is no error. The error comes later because an unexpected size for padded_outputs. It should not be a size None. Look at the input vector in the print "check point 1". It is a tensor of size (100,) with all values being 300. Then tf.reduce_max() should return 300 and tf.reshape() should return padded_outputs with size (100,300,500).

Comment: Can you replace all print statements with tf.print and update your question with the outputs?

Answer (score 1):

It should work by simply passing the reduced tensor as an argument:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1)

@tf.function
def reshape_on_max_value():
  tensor1 = tf.random.uniform((5, 2), maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32)
  tensor2 = tf.random.uniform((4, 1), maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32)
  x = tf.reduce_max(tensor1)
  tf.print(type(tensor1), type(tensor2))
  tf.print(tf.reshape(tensor2, [x, 1, 1]).shape)

reshape_on_max_value()
```

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
TensorShape([4, 1, 1])
```

Comment: what do you get if you type type(tensor1) or type(tensor2)?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Now I get the same results as you do. I don't understand why it doesnt work in my actual code. Do you know why the type of x is different in your code and in my question? the "x_3:0" part.

Comment: Please post your actual code... the x_3 part is just the tensor name.